# What does last part of Android NDK version mean?

Tags: semantic-versioning

When I get to download Android NDK, I can see version name like below.

```
android {
    ndkVersion "25.2.9519653"
}
```

This looks like semantic versioning to me.
But patch version seem to be too big so I'm not sure.
I don't think there were 9519653 patches and there must be some rules to read this number.

What does patch number 9519653 mean?

I tried to find answer with google and read change logs of Android NDK.
I thought there would be some descriptions about version name but this was not that easy.
I could check Android NDK version match RegEx of SemVer with site below.
https://regex101.com/r/Ly7O1x/3/

Comment: Doesn't look like strict semver. The trailing number is likely a build number.

Comment: The Major.minor.patch version triple was in use for decades before semantic versioning was commonly adopted and SemVer is only one of many semantic versioning schemes.  There's often no way to disambiguate between them.  Unless a numeric field looks like a date, large field numbers in no way rule out that it could be SemVer.  But ya, that patch does look like it could be a build number.